# Properties of Google Earth Engine GeoTIFF export

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, metadata, arccatalog

I am adding a couple of properties to an export, named 'elev' and 'threshold'. My objective is to have those properties embebed in the exported GeoTIFF, however, when I open the exported GeoTIFF and try to find those properties using ArcMap or ArcCatalog I cannot find them. Anyone knows how to properly export/display those properties on exported TIFFs?

```js
// Export the result.
  var nameexp1 = 'Mask_' + start + '_' + end;
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: result.int().unmask(-9999).set('elev',demval,'threshold',mndwival),
  description: nameexp1,
  scale: 30, maxPixels: 228612704,
  region: ROI
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to actually attach the metadata to an exporting image, you could consider exporting the metadata as a .csv file by using `Export.table.toDrive()` and linking the metadata in ArcGIS based on the image name or similar.

There is also the option by adding the metadata value as a band by using `.addBands()`, but from a datastorage perspective that might be inconvenient i guess?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible yet other than the suggestions already provided.
You can track the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204353357):